# rewriterule customization for canonical

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is the code I'm working with now inside my htaccess file.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|webp|html)(\.gz)?(\?.*)?$"> 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* - [E=CANONICAL:http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI},NE]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule .* - [E=CANONICAL:https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI},NE]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c> 
Header set Link "<%{CANONICAL}e>; rel=\"canonical\"" 
</IfModule> 
</FilesMatch>
```

What I am trying to do is get the canonical here to be different than the HTTP_HOST.

Let's just say that HTTP_HOST now is example.com/es/ but what I need this canonical to be is example.com/en/

How can I use the above code with modification to rewrite the URL of the canonical to reflect example.com/en/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off
RewriteCond http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)/es/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=CANONICAL:%1/en/%2,NE,S=1]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off
RewriteRule .* - [E=CANONICAL:http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI},NE]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You fixed it mate! Thanks a bunch for helping out.